# Custom Attribute For Customer Entity is not working in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, eav, customer-attribute

I am trying to add a customer attribute `Mobile` in `customer_entity_varchar` and It's not working. I can't see my attribute in `eav_attribute` table. Here are my codes.

**local/Vaibhav/Mobile/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<config>
        <modules>
            <Vaibhav_Mobile>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Vaibhav_Mobile>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <resources>
                <Vaibhav_Mobile_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>Vaibhav_Mobile</module>
                        <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                    </setup>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_setup</use>
                    </connection>
                </Vaibhav_Mobile_setup>
                <Vaibhav_Mobile_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                </Vaibhav_Mobile_write>
                <Vaibhav_Mobile_read>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_read</use>
                    </connection>
                </Vaibhav_Mobile_read>
            </resources>
        </global>
    </config>
```

**local/Vaibhav/Mobile/sql/vaibhav_mobile_setup/install-0.1.0.php**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "mobile",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Mobile",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => "Mobile"

        ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "mobile");


$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'mobile',
    '999'  //sort_order
);

$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
                ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
                ->setData("is_system", 0)
                ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
                ->setData("is_visible", 1)
                ->setData("sort_order", 100)
                ;
        $attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

**etc/modules/Vaibhav_Mobile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Vaibhav_Mobile>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Vaibhav_Mobile>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

I can't see any error also. Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Comment: check **core_resource**  table what version of your module?

Comment: @PrasantaHatui I can't see in core_resource table also. It's very weird. However, I can see in the admin panel -> system -> configuration -> advance

Comment: Please ensure your script was executed or not

Comment: You can try to create an upgrade script

Comment: @PrasantaHatui I have tried with upgrade script also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `config.xml` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vaibhav_Mobile>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Vaibhav_Mobile>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <vaibhav_mobile_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Vaibhav_Mobile</module>
                    <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </vaibhav_mobile_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Relevant change which you need to notice here is change of resource node. Here it is changed to `vaibhav_mobile_setup` instead of `Vaibhav_Mobile_setup`, which is important in order to correctly point towards your install script location.

After these changes made, you need to clear all cache and remove the entry corresponds to your module from `core_resource` table if it exists.

### EDIT

It is always a good habit to define your own setup resources for your module. Here you are trying to reuse `Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup` resource class, which has no issue in use case. But it is always better to define your own setup resource class, let's say `Vaibhav_Mobile_Model_Customer_Setup` and which then inherits from `Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup`.

Comment: Should I create Model Class also? As of now there is no Model Class.

Comment: You can avoid that in that case.

Comment: Just now I made the changes as you said. Still, I can't find in `core_resource`

Comment: okay. put your site in development mode and try again. Also look for any log errors in `var/log` folder. Also please see my edit.

Comment: Also in your further check. Put a `die()` call in your install script. It is the best way to check whether your install script is working or not

Comment: Rajeev, I have repeated all the steps as you have mentioned. Still, nothing happened.

Comment: Rajeev it works, I just disabled all the cache

Comment: Yes that is also I mentioned in my answer. If this helped you, feel free to accept it.